# spresense LTEボードを使用した AWS-IoT 送信時に mbedtls_ssl_write() error が発生する

Tags: spresense

LteGnssTrackerを参考にAWS-IoTにデータを送信すると、何時間か経過してエラーが頻発します。
ソースは単純で以下になります。

```
mqttClient.beginMessage(topic_ini);
mqttClient.print(buff); 
mqttClient.endMessage();
```

エラーの状態は以下の3種類あります。

(1)ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x50
(2)ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x7100
(3)ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x4e

(1)(2)の場合は、connect()を再実行で復帰できますが、
(3)の場合はendMessage()で10分程度フリーズして(endMessageから戻ってこない)、
その後、connect()を再実行で復帰できる時と、できない時があります。

動作環境は、SPRESENSE v2.5.1、LTE RK2.1.2.10.108.54にUpdateしてます。
そ
対処方法をご存じの方、ご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0):

MbedTLSのエラーコードは、以下の2ファイルに定義されております。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/externals/mbedtls/mbedtls-v2/include/mbedtls/ssl.h#L78
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/externals/mbedtls/mbedtls-v2/include/mbedtls/net_sockets.h#L52

これによると、エラー内容は以下のようになります。

(1) ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x50 → `Connection was reset by peer.`
(2) ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x7100 → `Bad input parameters to function.`
(3) ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x4e → `Sending information through the socket failed.`

(1) は単純に接続相手から切断されてしまっていると思います。
(2) については、`mbedtls_ssl_write`に与えるパラメータに不備があるという意味なので、パラメータが誤っているか、外的要因でパラメータが使用できなくなってしまったかが考えられます。
(3) については、Socketの送信に失敗しているので、接続相手が見つからなくなった(Closeはされていないのに通信できない)ことが考えられます。

私の経験上、(3)は1日に1度ほどLTEネットワークからIPアドレスが変更されたタイミングで起きていることが多いです。
なので、このエラーが発生しているときはIPを変える作業が裏で走っているため、処理に時間がかかっているのではないかと思います。

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

ご回答ありがとうございました。
(2) ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x7100
これに関しては、LTEボードをRK2⇒RK3に変えたところ全く出なくなりました。
(3) ERROR: mbedtls_ssl_write() error : -0x4e
これはNATタイプのSIMを使用すると出やすいとSIMメーカーの見解を聞きました。
動的グローバルIPのSIMにすると良くなるかもとのことでした。

結果的にフリーズ現象を止めることは出来ていませんので、
フリーズ時にウォッチドッグを使い、再スタートさせて対処しました。